# Firebase | React - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to map my product collection over the <CatalogItem /> component but receive 2 null arrays before the console shows the data in the array. Because of this I get an error:

> caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

[image: console error]

Once I am able to get the [0] from the array without the null arrays I believe the return will work appropriately.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Row, Image, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import CatalogItem from "../../components/CatalogItem";
import hero from '../../Images/sabrianna-CCpQ12CZ2Pc-unsplash.jpg'
import '../../App.css'
import Header from "../../components/Navigation";
// import { productList } from "../../data";
import Footer from '../../components/Footer'
import CategoryMenu from '../../components/CategoryMenu'

import MessageOffcanvas from "../../components/MessageOffcanvas/index"
import {db} from '../../config/firebase'
import {  collection, query, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

function Catalog() {
  
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]
  );

  const productsRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const productRef = query(collection(db, 'products'))
    onSnapshot(productRef, (snapshot) => {
      setProduct(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        data: doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }))) 
      productsRef.current = product;

    });
    console.info(product)
  },)
  
  return (
    <>
    <Header />
    
    <MessageOffcanvas />
    <Container fluid='true' className='m-0 p-0' >
      <Row>
        <Image src={hero}  style={{objectFit: "cover", height:'500px'}} fluid/>
      </Row>
    </Container>
      <h2 className="align-items-center text-white p-2">Catalog</h2>

      <CategoryMenu />
      
      <Row xxl={4} xl={3} lg={2} md={2} sm={1} xs={1} className="g-3 p-3">

      {productsRef.current.map((data) => (
        <CatalogItem
        key={data.id}
        />

      ))}
      </Row>
      <br></br>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default Catalog;
```

Comment: `productsRef.current` is likely to still be `null` when initialised with `useRef`, perhaps you could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `{productsRef.current?.map(...)}` when attempting to loop through the object. Out of interest, why are you not using the value set for `product` after the `setProduct` call is made?